# One specific product detail page returns 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, 404

I have check the visibiity option and status of that product is also enabled and also reindex the data but  still one product is returning 404 error.

https://qa2.yeswellness.com/vitamins-and-minerals/greens-and-antioxidants/chlorella.html.Check first product on the list.

Comment: The URL is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the stock-settings? Per default Magento creates new products as "out of stock" and this one might still be on the default settings.
Open the product in the admin panel, head for inventory and check if everything is good. If you changed something, reindex data and all should be fine.

Comment: yes I have checked this one as well and product is in stock

Comment: Have you checked visibility settings on all available levels (website, store and storeview)? How are your products created? Is the product assigned to the right website and category? Sadly I get a 403 Forbidden when trying to open your site.

Comment: From where can i check the visibility settings ? i am newbie to the magento so i dont have much information about it?

Comment: Its on the product edit page in the admin panel right in the general section under then URL-Key part. It has 4 options (nothing, search only, catalog only or both).

Comment: It is set to the catalog right now, is it corect?

Comment: That should enable this product to be visible in the catalog (if the right category, website, etc is used).

Comment: It is set to catalog but it is still returns 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the following category is enabled: `Greens and Antioxidants`
If enabled, verify that you have the correct `URL_KEY` for the category in your URL.

The product may be enabled and you could be using the wrong URL.

This category loads: https://www.yeswellness.com/vitamins-and-minerals.html
This one does not: https://www.yeswellness.com/vitamins-and-minerals/greens-and-antioxidants.html